# Bitnami MEANstack: Cannot find module 'mongoose'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack, bitnami

I've encountered the problem after trying to connect MongoDB on my project. I've followed the instructions on a native installation this [tutorial](https://wiki.bitnami.com/index.php?title=Infrastructure_Stacks/BitNami_MEAN_Stack_(MongoDB%2C_Express%2C_Angular%2C_Node.js)#Connecting_to_MongoDB) and after executing the command `node bin\www`, I get the error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'mongoose'
```

How should I fix this problem? Thanks in advance!

Regards, Daryll

Answer (score 2):

You should install the mongoose package from the Node Package Manager.

> npm install mongoose

Comment: tried it but i got an error. it says `gyp: directory\.node-gyp\4.1.1\common.gypi not found` and a configure error

Comment: i also tried to bypass the errors produced in installing mongoose and executed `node bin\www` and it had an `Error: connect ENOENT...`